# Find filename of picture inserted in a Word Document on a Mac

Tags: mac, ms-office

In a word document I included a pdf, that is a picture.

However I forgot where is the source location and how it is called.

Is there any way to find that out?

I use Mac OS Mojave 10.14.5 on a Mac Book Pro and Microsoft Word for Mac Version 16.26.

Answer (score 1):

There is a slight possibility that if you export your current document to a PDF, open it on Acrobat Reader, put your mouse over that image for a few seconds, a tooltip will come up and prompting you the original location of the image.

However, since your image was imported through a PDF but not a direct file, this method may not 100% work.